# How can I obtain a conditional distribution from a joint distribution using a MCMC sample?

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, markov-chain-montecarlo, joint-distribution

Suppose that $\theta = (\theta_1,\theta_2) \in{\mathbb R}^2$ are the parameters of a model, and that I can obtain a MCMC sample from the posterior distribution of $\theta \mid {\bf x}$.

Using the MCMC sample, how can I obtain the conditional posterior distribution

$$\theta_2 \mid \theta_1, {\bf x}\,?$$

Comment: mmm if $\theta_1$ is discrete... good luck with estimating the distribution from old samples, if it's discrete, you can just consider only the sample with that value of $\theta_1$

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Good point. Both parameters are continuous.

Comment: Do you have a particular value of $\theta_1$ in mind, or do you want the conditional posterior to be calculated for a wide range of values?

Comment: @jbowman Ideally, for a wide range of values, but I can reconsider if this is not a feasible task.

Comment: What sort of proposal distribution are you using?  Are the two parameters independent in the proposal, or can the proposal be factored as $f_2(\theta_2|\theta_1)f_1(\theta_1)$, or...?

Comment: @jbowman Do you mean the prior distribution? The prior is indeed independent.  For the MCMC, I have been playing with Stan and Gibbs samplers.

Comment: No, I mean the proposal distribution.   If the proposal has either of those two structures, it becomes easy to simply fix $\theta_1$ and generate only proposals for $\theta_2$.   Since this is now a one-dimensional problem, you should be able to get a good chain with a lot fewer iterations than in the two-dimensional case, which in turn makes it possible to do this for quite a few different values of $\theta_1$.  There are other approaches...

Comment: @jbowman I think that would only work for some samplers. It is an interesting pointer, but perhaps limited to samplers like MH or Gibbs.

Comment: @Xi'an I could accept that as an answer if you want to post it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one is using a Gibbs sampler, which is a [specific type of MCMC algorithm](http://amzn.to/2lQDmJR), the conditional distributions of $θ_1$ given $θ_2,x$ and of $θ_2$ given $θ_1,\mathbf x$ are a requirement for running the algorithm. Hence $\pi( θ_2|θ^0_1,\mathbf x)$ is available as a generative model, if not necessarily in closed form.

Otherwise, in the general case, a sample from $$\pi(\theta_1,\theta_2|\mathbf x)\propto p(\mathbf x|θ_1,θ_2)π(θ_1,θ_2)$$ does not provide direct information about $\pi( θ_2|θ^0_1,\mathbf x)$, except by using a [non-parametric estimator of the conditional density](https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/%7Ebhansen/papers/ncde.pdf). Except for special cases, one need run a new MCMC algorithm with target $$\pi( θ_2|θ^0_1,\mathbf x)\propto p(\mathbf x|θ^0_1,θ_2)π(θ^0_1,θ_2)$$where $θ^0_1$ is the value of $θ_1$ one wants to condition upon.